# Java Optimization with Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, optimization

I'm using a custom class `Foo` in Java as the key type in a `HashMap`. All the fields of `Foo` instances are immutable (they are declared final and private and are assigned values only in the constructor). Thus, the `hashCode()` of a given `Foo` object is also fixed, and for optimization purposes, I am calculating it in the constructor and simply returning that value in the `hashCode()` method.

Instances of `Foo` also have a `value()` method which returns a similar fixed value once the object has been instantiated. Currently I am also calculating it in the constructor and returning it in the method, but there is a difference between `hashCode()` and `value()`: `hashCode()` is called for the first time almost instantly after the object is created, but `value()` is called much later. I understand that having a separate Thread to calculate the hash-code would simply increase the run-time because of synchronization issues, but:

- is this a good way to calculate `value()`? Would it improve run-time at all?
- are simple `Threads` enough, or do I need to use pools etc.?

*Note:* this may seem like I'm optimizing the wrong parts of my program, but I've already worked on the 'correct' parts and brought the average run-time down from ~17 seconds to ~2 seconds. *Edit:* there will be upwards of 5000 `Foo` objects, and that's a conservative estimate.

Comment: in terms of conception and architecture, it would be weird, as `value()` would be able to return an invalid value for a time.

Comment: @njzk2 That's fine for my program; as I said, `value()` is called a long time after the object is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It definitely sounds like deferred calculation is a good approach here - and yes, if you create a lot of these objects, a thread pool is the way to go.

As for `value()`'s return value until it's ready, I would stay away from returning invalid values, and instead either make it blocking (and add some `isValueReady()` helper) or make it instantly return a "future" - some object that offers those same `isReady` and a blocking `get` methods.

Also, never rely on "much later" - always make sure the value there is ready before using it.

Comment: In theory, your answer sounds right to me, but in practice, something's going wrong: the program is taking more than 5 times the usual time to run. Which details should I provide to make my situation more specific?

Comment: @shardulc There are many possible variables, and I don't know your application. I would first look at two things: 1. how heavy is calculating `value()`? If creating a threadpool thread is heavier, it will never be worth it. 2. How CPU-starved is your application? If it has 100% CPU utilization, deferring a calculation will carry no benefit and you will still pay for the overhead. Honestly though, it might be something else altogether... I rely on profiling when it isn't obvious from the code or from debugging why something is slow.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) for `value` - create a static [fixedTheadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)) and [submit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)) the `value` calculations on it.  This way there's no risk that `value` will be accessed before it's available - the worst case is that whatever is accessing `value` will block on a [Future.get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) call (or [use the version with a timeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) if e.g. deadlock is a concern)

Because `Future.get` throws checked exceptions which can be a nuisance, you can wrap the `get` call in your class's getter method and wrap the checked exceptions in a `RuntimeException`

```
class MyClass {
    private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(/* some value that makes sense */);

    private final Future<Value> future;

    public MyClass() {
        future = executor.submit(/* Callable */);
    }

    public boolean isValueDone() {
        return future.isDone();
    }

    public Value value() {
        try {
            return future.get();
        } catch(InterruptedException|ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```